# PHP Creating new DateTime with different formats

Tags: php, date, datetime

The code below works fine until $dt4 gets created (UK format), $dt1 works fine for German format, $dt2 works fine for Dutch format, $dt3 works fine for US format, $dt4 fails as it says it is incorrect format so it couldn't parse it, so I tried using setlocale to en_GB before creating $dt4 however it did not help, any ideas?

```
    $dt = new DateTime('13.03.2014');
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');

    $dt2 = new DateTime('13-03-2014');
    echo $dt2->format('Y-m-d');

    $dt3 = new DateTime('03/13/2014');
    echo $dt3->format('Y-m-d');

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
    $dt4 = new DateTime('13/03/2014');
    echo $dt4->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: You're looking for [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `DateTime` doesn't seem to bother about locales from what I gather from this page describing valid [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). Instead, try your luck with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '13.03.2014', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can exchange 'd.m.Y' for any input format you need, and don't forget to set a DateTimeZone.